# Geospatial data usage in AgensGraph

Tags: geospatial, agens-graph

I want to know how the geospatial data like .shp file stored in AgensGraph?

I mean, does AgensGraph support the geo data?

I know the PostGIS extension, but I'm not trying to use the PostGIS.

I think AgensGraph should have a some structure like storage and functions for geo data. Please let me know the geo data is available or not.

Answer (score 2):

I writting to share my experience that deal with geo-spatial data in AgensGraph.

Basically AgensGraph object takes JSON format.

So you can store the data after the coverting SHP to GeoJSON.

The method of Converting process is refered heres

[Link 1](https://mygeodata.cloud/converter/shp-to-geojson)
[Link 2](http://techslides.com/demos/mapping/shapefile-geojson-converter.html)